# Openshift custom deployment strategy with an image of private repo

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am developing a custom deployment strategy of a **DeploymentConfig** in openshift. I want my image to be taken from private artifactory which needs authentication. However, in the custom strategy parameters I don't see anything relevant with **imagePullSecrets**

[image: customParameteres]

The [example](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.14/applications/deployments/deployment-strategies.html#deployments-custom-strategy_recreate-strategy) of openshift also does not mention anything about imagePull Secret:
[image: custom strategy]

How can I use an image pull secret for pulling an image at *DeploymentConfig.spec.strategy.customParams.image* ?